# NSButton cannot setaction

Tags: objective-c, ibaction, nsbutton

I am trying to add an action to a `NSButton` but it is not working

I create my `NSButtton` programmatically:

```
-(NSView *)rowTable:(CGFloat) heightOnPanel :(NSString *) textValue: (CGFloat) width: (CGFloat) height :(int) intColor{
    NSView *viewce = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, heightOnPanel, 320, 40)];
    NSButton *layerBt = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height)];

    [layerBt setTitle:textValue];

    [layerBt setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
    [layerBt setTarget:nil];
    [layerBt setAction:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    [viewce addSubview:layerBt];

    return viewce;
}
```

and here is `IBAction` method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"hello world");
}
```

Could you point me to what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You are aware that your `target` is `nil`, yes? So how do you imagine your `buttonPressed:` is going to be called?

Comment: thank you matt - i am missing something this is why I asked here. No need to be rude

Comment: Not rudeness, I'm asking you what you think your code does. `nil` target, so when the button is pressed it sends the action message to _whom_? There _is_ such a thing as a `nil` targeted action, so perhaps you have a justification for expecting this to work. I am a rubber ducky: explain your code to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be valid if the object with the method `buttonPressed:` is a member of the responder chain. If it isn't you should set the target explicitly:

```
[layerBt setTarget:theTarget];
[layerBt setAction:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
```

where `theTarget` implements `buttonPressed:`.